# Will cascading two routers separate both networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

If I plug a second router with DHCP on and a different subnet, will that separate the networks and keep them from communicating with each other? One of my family members had malware recently and I really just want to limit any damage from happening in the future to my devices and others on the network.

Here is what I want to do :

> Bridged ISP modem —> main router(192.168.1.1)(my devices) —> second
>   router(192.168.5.1)(LAN TO WAN CASCADING)(family devices)

I have two D-LINK DIR-655 model C routers and they do not offer VLAN support.
EDIT: apparently they do offer a VLAN for the isolated guest zone networ function, I need to look into this.

There is also a second reason I want to do this, the far end of my home has poor 2.4GHz Wi-Fi and this setup would fix that as I plan to run a cat 6 cable to a different room from my office where I don’t need  Wi-Fi and the main router and modem is. Double NAT is not an issue as only basic web access is needed and the video games are connected to the first router.

Answer (score 3):

The both Networks 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.5.0/24 will be separated. Due to NAT, computers from Internet will have no access to both LANs without port forwarding, and computers in 192.168.1.0/24 will have no access to 192.168.5.0/24 without port forwarding.

Computers in 192.168.5.0/24 will have access to 192.168.1.0/24 if they know the IP addresses. So actually 192.168.5.0/24 is better protected. If you can arrange it from cabling, put your computers in 192.168.5.0/24, and computers that are potentially endangered by malware in  192.168.1.0/24.

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> If I plug a second router with DHCP on and a different subnet, will
>   that separate the networks and keep them from communicating with each
>   other?

And say this:

> I have two D-LINK DIR-655 model C routers and they do not offer VLAN
>   support.

First the layout you mention won’t separate the two networks. One device becomes another device on the first device’s network. Meaning while you want the subnets to be different via the main one begin `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.5.1`, they will all be members of the same network; 192.168.x.x.

Maybe of the subnet mask on `192.168.5.1` was `255.255.255.0` and  `192.168.1.1` was `255.255.0.0` that could work. But t still doesn’t feel right to me.

What you really want is a true LAN… But that said you also say this:

> One of my family members had malware recently and I really just want
>   to limit any damage from happening in the future to my devices and
>   others on the network.

What kind of malware? And why do you believe VLAN separation would minimize the image of a malware infection? Do you believe that if the `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.5.1` networks would be separated in such a way only the bridged ISP modem would be accessible then if a machine is infected on `192.168.1.1` it would not be able to contact `192.168.5.1`?

Logically that would make sense. But it depends on the malware and it’s behavior. So in my opinion, your idea of VLAN separation won’t work as expected this way… And past that it still doesn’t guarantee malware protection.

Answer (score 0):

How are your family members connected? WiFi only? Some routers offer you an option to disable WiFi communiciation between connected devices (either for all or specific members), which will no longer allow them to connect or talk to any other device on the local network, but they're able to access the internet/WAN just as usual.